# How to select except certain id from database table

Tags: mysql

I've database table with the following pageid's 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 --> will added more.
and i'm using

```
$sql ="select * from pages order by pageid";
$result= mysql_query($sql);
while($page= mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "$page[pagetitle]";
}
```

Now i want to select all except pageid=4 ! so that it won't show the page title that have pageid = 4 and show the others 1,2,3,5,6 ---> and any other added.

How to say select all except !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply add a `WHERE` clause `WHERE pageid <> 4`:

```
$sql ="select * from pages WHERE pageid <> 4 order by pageid";
$result= mysql_query($sql);
while($page= mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  echo $page['pagetitle'];
}
```

Or replace with a PHP variable to make it dynamic:

```
$exclpage = 4;
$sql ="SELECT * FROM pages WHERE pageid <> $exclpage ORDER BY pageid";
```

If you have multiple pageids to exclude, use a `NOT IN()` clause:

```
// Exclude pages 4,5,9
$sql ="SELECT * FROM pages WHERE pageid NOT IN (4,5,9) ORDER BY pageid";
```

#### Update:

Since this answer has more recently had some attention, it is advisable to use prepared statements and parameterize the variables instead of variables directly in the query, particularly if the variables are the result of any user input.

```
$sql ="SELECT * FROM pages WHERE pageid <> ? ORDER BY pageid";
// Bind ? according to your preferred API's method, such as MySQLi::bind_param() or PDO::bindParam()
```

Comment: thank a lot for this explain , i've been all time thinking how to exclude some pages.

Comment: @JackBen Happy to help. Be sure to accept the answer if you're satisfied with it.

Comment: You are superior, I was just thinking about this for an add function where you can only add stuff witch is not already added. So you can chose from an select-box witch only contains the stuff witch is not added yet. Good work this makes me happy! And I have a more efficient way to deal with double input. Now i don't need to write a validation function for this.

Answer (score 0):

Just today I did something like this, but with a subquery (I use t-sql):

```
select * from pages 
WHERE pageid NOT IN (select pageid from myTable where 'some conditions...') 
order by pageid
```

Hope you find it usefull

Comment: Looks overly complicated, what's wrong with `select * from pages where NOT( some conditions )`

Comment: @Johan: it was an example of some conditions :)